# ForeColor being reset in SplitContainer on initialization and resize

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, splitcontainer

I noticed some unusual behavior when using different fore-colored ListViewItems in a ListView inside a SplitContainer.  Initially the colors aren't usually displayed (though sometimes they are, mysteriously), but they show up when items are selected.  Resizing the window also seems to wipe out any colors in the ListViewItems (if the anchors are set to resize it along with the panel), resetting all items to the original black ForeColor.  Calling invalidate or refresh after adding the ListViewItems makes no difference, they are still initially drawn as black until clicked on.  Note that this problem doesn't occur when the ListView is outside of the SplitContainer.

To reproduce, create a new windows forms project, add a SplitContainer, and add a ListView to one side of it.  Set the ListView's View property to List, and anchor it on all sides for resizing.  Then use the following code after InitializeComponent to setup the items:

```
ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem("blah blah blah blah blah 1");
listViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

listViewItem = new ListViewItem("blah blah blah blah blah 2");
listViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

listViewItem = new ListViewItem("blah blah blah blah blah 3");
listViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Green;
listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Any idea how to fix this?  I've found some similar questions but no real solution to the problem.  Thanks for the help.

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express with .Net Framework 4.  The color problems happen on both Windows XP and 7.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: No repro.  My ListViewItems keep their ForeColors all the time.